# Template is not a valid Org entry or tree

Tags: org-capture

There is a [previous post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47284/org-capture-template-error-template-is-not-a-valid-org-entry-or-tree) for that error, but it didn't help in my case. What could be causing the error?

Set up:

```
$ ls -a $HOME/org
 .   ..  '#notes.org#'   .#notes.org   .notes.org   .notes.org~   tpl-todo.txt
$ cat '$HOME/.emacs'
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-capture-templates
   '(("t" "TODO entry" entry
      (file+headline ".notes.org" "Get Things Done")
      "tpl-todo.txt" :empty-lines-after 1)))
 '(org-default-notes-file "$HOME/org/.notes.org")
 '(org-directory "$HOME/org")
 '(org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "DONE" "CANCEL")))
 '(package-archives
   '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(emacsql-mysql csv-mode gh-md emojify-logos emojify gnu-elpa org auctex)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
$ cat $HOME/org/tpl-todo.txt
* TODO %^(description)
%? 'cursor
:LOGBOOK:
- Added: %U
:END:
$ cat $HOME/org/.notes.org
* Get Things Done
```

Also tried with this replacement:

```
'(org-capture-templates
  '(("t" "TODO entry" entry
     (file+headline "$HOME/org/.notes.org" "Get Things Done")
     "$HOME/org/tpl-todo.txt" :empty-lines-after 1)))
```

Instruction:

```
M-x org-capture
t
```

Message:

```
org-capture: Capture template ‘t’: Template is not a valid Org entry or tree
```

Update 1

Based on a comment, I modified the setup as follows:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-capture-templates
   '(("t" "TODO entry" entry
      (file+headline "/home/[user]/org/.notes.org" "Get Things Done")
      file "/home/[user]/org/tpl-todo.txt" :empty-lines-after 1)))
 '(org-default-notes-file "/home/[user]/org/.notes.org")
 '(org-directory "/home/[user]/org")
 '(org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "DONE" "CANCEL")))
 '(package-archives
   '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(emacsql-mysql csv-mode gh-md emojify-logos emojify gnu-elpa org auctex)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
```

Comment: Replace `$HOME` with `~` in the elisp: I do not think emacs expands shell vars in strings (at least, mine doesn't).  Also, in the replacement version, it should be `(file "/path/to/template")` not just `"/path/to/template"`.

Comment: @FranBurstall I did `$HOME` after realizing `~` wasn't working, and now I've replaced it by "/homer/[username]". And based on your comment, I've also prepend `file ` to  "$HOME/org/tpl-todo.txt`. I will put the whole as an update in the post.

Comment: The syntax is wrong: try `'(org-capture-templates
   '(("t" "TODO entry" entry
      (file+headline "/home/[user]/org/.notes.org" "Get Things Done")
      (file "/home/[user]/org/tpl-todo.txt") :empty-lines-after 1)))` with the template file specification in parens (untested).

Comment: @NickD Now it works. Since I last posted I realized `(.)` missing around `file "/home/[user]/org/tpl-todo.txt", but that still didn't solve it, so there must be something else.

Comment: So what else did you change to make it work?

Comment: @NickD I pasted your solution. Perhaps I had left out a typo, or spaces matter.

Comment: OK - thanks for the clarification. I posted the comment as an answer based on your verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Making the comment into an answer.]

The syntax is wrong - try this:

```el
...
'(org-capture-templates
    '(("t" "TODO entry" entry
       (file+headline "/home/[user]/org/.notes.org" "Get Things Done")
       (file "/home/[user]/org/tpl-todo.txt") :empty-lines-after 1)))
...
```

with the template file specification in parens.

At the time I posted the comment, it was untested, but the OP tried it and verified that the problem is resolved.